# Liferay7.1GA4 Antivirus implementation java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: liferay, classloader, classnotfoundexception, antivirus

As stated in the documentation https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.1-latest/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html to implement an antivirus for file upload we developed an antivirus class that implements com.liferay.document.library.kernel.antivirus.AntivirusScanner and we added the following property in the portal-ext.properties

```
dl.store.antivirus.enabled=true
dl.store.antivirus.impl=it.antivirus.scanner.CustomAntivirusScanner
```

but when we start the portal we get the following error:

```
2021-04-16 15:26:29.356 ERROR [Portal Spring Init Thread][InstancePool:114] Unable to load it.antivirus.scanner.CustomAntivirusScanner with the portal class loader or the current context class loader
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.antivirus.scanner.CustomAntivirusScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InstancePool.get(InstancePool.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InstancePool.get(InstancePool.java:33)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.antivirus.AntivirusScannerImpl.<init>(AntivirusScannerImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.bean.LiferayBeanFactory.populateBean(LiferayBeanFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:278)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

maybe we are missing something in the @Component definition?

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    service = AntivirusScanner.class
)
```

or in the bnd.bnd?

```
Bundle-Name: CustomAntivirusScanner
Bundle-SymbolicName: it.antivirus.scanner
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: On a quick glance, it doesn't look like InstancePool (or the Antivirus configuration / loader) is OSGi-aware and needs classes to be on the portal classloader... But I might have missed something, just checked quickly. If you manage to write a bundleactivator that places your implementation in the InstancePool, you might be lucky.

Comment: @OlafKock we've just tried to make a bundle activator module to put an instance of the CustomAntivirus class into the InstancePool, but the activator start function is called after the initial check, the error comes immediately after INFO  [main][ModuleFrameworkImpl:1326] Starting initial bundles, do you have some suggestion on how to have the class available into the portal class loader?

Comment: Also, [please note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)